# osTicket Open Source Alternative

Tags: php, ticket-system

For anybody who uses [osTicket](http://osticket.com/) you may have noticed that it is no longer being developed and it has been two years since the latest update. I want to switch to a open source ticket software which is supported and updated.

Any tips on what to use?

I have obviously googled and found some great looking solutions but I would be interested in getting opinions from people who actually use alternatives.

Comment: You should at least list the great looking solutions otherwise your question is not really helpful. Also see the related questions on the right.

Comment: See: www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1288243/osticket-whats-better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider [OTRS](http://otrs.com) - it is open source, and actively developed. It has a strong company backing it, a vast number of bigger and smaller companies using it, and it has a strong community with active mailing lists and forums.

Answer (score 5):

Actually osTicket isn't dead.  In fact there were several release candidates available at the time that this question was posted. Their new stable version 1.7ST (desoto) was also released on 02 apr 2013. (After 6 released candidates [RC] and several developer preview releases [DPR])

Check it out at: https://github.com/osticket
or at http://osticket.com

Answer (score 2):

You could also use GLPI. It is written on the php/apache/mySQL stack, was started in 2003 (I think) and is still actively developed: 1 major release abut every 2 years and minor ones 3-4/year. 
It is translated in about 40 languages.
Very good as a ticketing system, but also very strong for asset inventory (integration with Fusion Inventory and OCS Inventory).